# Angular Rxjs: Write custom operator to replace shareReplay() with my own business logic

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

First of all thank you for your time.

I would like to get a nudge into the right direction regarding making my own custom Rxjs operator that results into the same as shareReplay() except when I want it to update.

Basically we have a session storage variable which sets the users organization AND a JWT token that contains the organization of the user (Token is single source of truth).
Based upon that organization we have API data that is just set in stone for the session. Only if the user changes organization we would like to refresh that data and make a new call. shareReplay() is perfect to use, except I don't know how I can get my own logic to check if I need to refresh. (As in, if JWTToken === sessionstorage.getItem('organization')).

Currently I have something like this, but at the moment I am not experienced enough with Rxjs to do it properly, any help is appreciated! Btw, If you have a better approach, thats fine too. I just thought it would be easy to reuse the operator.

- Rxjs version 6.5.5
- Angular version 12.1.0

```
/**
 * Replay this when organization is the same
 * @returns
 */
export function replayWhenSameOrganization<T>() {
  return function (source: Observable<T>) {
    if (this.token.organization === sessionStorage.getItem('organization')) {
      return source;
    } else {
      return new Observable<T>((subscriber) => {
        source.subscribe({
          next(value) {
            subscriber.next(value);
          },
          error(error) {
            subscriber.error(error);
          },
          complete() {
            subscriber.complete();
          },
        });
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Currently shareReplay would be nice as I can rewrite a legacy application that is using subscribe in subscribe every component again for the same data, resulting in stepping through the router through 7 components, and 7 times its calling the same URL with the same response, I think it has been done to fight the refresh issue. shareReplay resolves this as it will send the last received value if there is any and will send a request if there is none. My issue is that I need to set a condition on when I actually want to get fresh server data even if I have a value already. ( In the case of the user switching organizations without refreshing the app ). I know using Ngrx might be a solution as you can send an action to reset the store, except the team is not there yet.

**Legacy**

APISERVICE

```
GetConfig() {
  return this.http.get('apiurl/config');
}
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.apiService.GetConfig().subscribe(config => {
     this.apiService.GetComponentData(config.id).subscribe( 
        componentdata => { 
          this.componentdata = componentdata;
        }
     );
   })
}
```

**My refactor idea**

I would like to use the async pipe in the HTML files and rewrite some stuff as I think it will improve readability and makes the front-end code more testable as you can mock Observable values.

APISERVICE

```
GetConfig(): Observable<IConfig> {
  return this.http.get('apiurl/config').pipe(
    tap(config => this.config = config),
    shareReplay()
  )
}
```

```
$componentData: Observable<ComponentData> = this.getComponentData();

ngOnInit(): void {}

getComponentData(): Observable<ComponentData> {
  return this.apiService.$config.pipe(
       mergeMap(config => 
            this.apiService.GetComponentDataByConfig(config)
       )
   )
}
```

Comment: can you please share a code snippet to illustrate your use case, its not very clear from the text. Why is shareReplay perfect in this case?

Comment: @Jensen Thank you for your response, I tried to give more context with code examples. If I still explained it wrongly, don't hesitate to ask for more clear explanation.

Comment: so when the organization changes you want the config$ observable in your component to return something else? If thats the case an event should be generated somewhere right? The observable will not change without any trigger

Comment: That is true @Jensen , I am looking for a solution that is both reusable and encapsulated, hence why I thought of a custom Rxjs operator. But I am not sure, how would you handle this? Thank you